# Edit existing items in a Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I've created a homepage, that simply has a sentence as the content

[image: Customized home page]

I've edited the settings so that this the front page of the website.

However, given the theme that I am using, when I go to the home page, this is what I see

[image: Actual home page]

I can see the content of my home page at the very bottom, but before that, there is a slider and a couple of blocks (that presumably come with the theme).

I'd like to know either how to remove these default blocks, or edit them myself to include links to other pages.

Also, as you can probably tell, I am very new to Wordpress. Are there any good documentations for beginners that would teach me how to create pages, edit and customize them so that I can have control over the whole page (as a regular website)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should edit by the php file, so if u don't know PHP start [here](http://php.net/).

**Go to : menu > appereance > editor.**

Here u see all the files you need. The file you should edit change with the theme.. so go through the code.

**Maybe**, it's under `header.php`

Comment: I thought the whole point of Wordpress was so that I didn't have to edit code or have a background in technical knowledge? Maybe I've misunderstood. I'm more than willing to learn the language, but given my timeframe of something I have to deliver, I'm not sure that will be possible.

Comment: Yes, u need it if u want use wordpress and make a good site.. So you should know the basics of front end programming ([HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/),[JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)) and [PHP](http://php.net/) because wordpress is based on it.

Without this knowledge, you can do something.. but maybe it will not match with your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

The html code you get above your content is inserted from the page template assigned to your homepage. Thus, if you want to modify it somehow you should go Editor Panel in Appearance Menu, then edit desired template. You can also create your own template with structure you actually want and assign it to that page.

As for a documentation, I think you're going to be good with the [official one](https://developer.wordpress.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can edit it by going appearence->editor with php code, be careful when you doing this

if you want to edit a header, you can find header.php in that particular theme

same with footer.php and you customize the design by clicking appearance->customize